# How can I force a CXF client to disconnect after receiving a FIN packet

Tags: java, networking, tcp, cxf, mule

I have a CXF generated client that successfully calls a web service and receives a response however the client sits and waits and does not disconnect until the read time out expires.

Using wireshark I have found that the server sends a TCP FIN packet and is returned a ACK and then disconnects, however my client then sends its FIN packet and sits and waits for a ACK response that never comes.

Is there a way to configure the cxf client to handle this scenario?

I have tested this with a .NET client and it seems to handle it without waiting.

Many Thanks

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with CXF itself, more on how sockets are created.

Comment: Please post the WireShark dump of the connection close.

Comment: Perhaps some firewall on the server or in between is aborting the connection and then silently dropping all packets for an "unestablished" connection.  The server should be in `FIN_WAIT_2` and thus responding to your client.  http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:TCP_CLOSE.svg&page=1

Comment: Thanks for the response but I dont believe its a firewall issue as and I can reproduce the problem by hosting their test harness on my local machine and it has the same behaviour

Comment: Hi Brian, sorry Im not sure how to export the wireshark's trace. its ssl encrypted but the last packet received info is "Encrypted Alert" and the flags set are  (FIN, PSH, ACK). I then send an "alphatech-lm > https [ACK]" then  "Encrypted Alert" with flags (ACK) then an alphatech-lm > https [FIN, ACK]. This is when it times out

Comment: Note that firewalls can exist on a single machine.  What OS is this?  The problem is that TCP must respond.  If the connection is still closing, it must ACK your FIN.  If the connection is completely gone, it must RST your FIN.  For you to not get any reply means something is dropping the packet.

Comment: Hi Brian, it is windows 2003 and you are right I have checked again and I am getting a RST to my FIN and then a time out?

Comment: I have also done some tests on different versions of cxf and the newer versions seem to handle the problem, unfortunately the version I am using (2.5.1) is integrated into Mule ESB and i cannot upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug in the version of CXF being used (2.5.1).

Its been resolved in later versions 2.5.6 and above..